# Replacing row values by column name in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame as below

```
df<- data.frame(a = c(1,2,3,4,5), 
                b = c(6,7,8,9,10), 
                c = c(11,12,13,14,15), 
                z = c("b","c","a","a","b"))
```

I'm trying to replace row values where that row's column name is equal to the value in column Z. The desired output is below

```
   a  b  c z
1  1 NA 11 b
2  2  7 NA c
3 NA  8 13 a
4 NA  9 14 a
5  5 NA 15 b
```

I was thinking something like the following code applied to each row

```
If column name is equal to Z, replace value with NA
```

But can't figure it out. Any help appreciated

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Matrix indexing `match`-ing the `z` column to the `colnames`

```
df[cbind(seq(nrow(df)),match(df$z,colnames(df[1:3])))] <- NA
df

   a  b  c z
1  1 NA 11 b
2  2  7 NA c
3 NA  8 13 a
4 NA  9 14 a
5  5 NA 15 b
```

Answer (score 1):

This is only going to work if the columns with the letters are in lexigraphic order:

```
> df[cbind(1:5,as.numeric(df$z))] <- rep(NA,5)
> df
   a  b  c z
1  1 NA 11 b
2  2  7 NA c
3 NA  8 13 a
4 NA  9 14 a
5  5 NA 15 b
```

Comment: No need for the `rep()` - vector recycling will take care of it.

Comment: Yeah. I was getting other errors and put it in., although never length mismatch one that would have required rep(). Yours is better in other ways as well.